# Фильтрация таблицы

Tags: javascript

На странице есть таблица, сверстанная div'ами, есть скрипт который фильтрует эту таблицу, при вводе необходимого значения в поле #searchInput, но суть в том, что в таблице изначально, при загрузке страницы, есть строки, которые скрыты свойством `display:none`, и если воспользоваться фильтром и потом стереть текст из фильтра, то отображаются все строки, даже те которые были скрыты при загрузке страницы. Можно ли это как-то обойти и скрывать/отображать только строки, которые не были изначально скрыты

```
let input = document.querySelector("#searchInput");
let arrData = document.getElementsByClassName('trading__market-table-row');
input.addEventListener('blur', showChoice);

function showChoice(event){
let value = event.target.value;
if (value === ""){
    for (let i=0; i<arrData.length; i++){
        let item = arrData[i]
        item.style.display = ""
    }
    return
}
for (let i=0; i<arrData.length; i++){
    let item = arrData[i]
    if (item.id !== value) {
        item.style.display = "none"
    } else {
        item.style.display = ""
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Можешь проверять значение input'a на пустоту, если там пусто то скрывать то что должно быть скрыто

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете заранее отфильтровать полученные строки и оставить только не скрытые и уже по ним проводить поиск. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexaaaant/q2sLac4k/13/)

```
const rowsWithoutHidden = rows.filter((row) => {
if (!row.classList.contains('hidden')) {
return row;
```

}
})

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но  у меня строки изначально имеют просто стиль display:none, у них нет добавочного класса hidden

Comment: Смог сделать, спасибо за помощь